# Subset a SpatialLinesDataFrame in R based on the name field containing a certain string

Tags: r, line

I have a SpatialLinesDataFrame in R that is a road network dataset. The names of certain roads begin with the string "NH" to indicate that these are national highways. E.g., NH44, NH75 etc. Roads that are not national highways have names beginning with other strings.

I want to subset the roads dataset to include just roads that are national highways. Is there any way to do this in R?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your name is in a column called `name` and your spatial lines object is called `d`, you can do the same as with any data frame in R, and select rows by some logical operation. Here I use `grepl` to match a string starting `NH`:

```
> d = data.frame(name=c("M1","NH2","Not NH","NH3","NHx"),z=1:5)
> d[which(grepl("^NH",d$name)),]
  name z
2  NH2 2
4  NH3 4
5  NHx 5
```

Note my test cases includes something with `NH` not at the start.